# Django: Views.py needs to access Class and Function in another python file

Tags: python, django

in my helper.py I have a class and a function definition:

```
class Suites():
    NAME_SUITE = ['NATE', 'TOM', 'TED', 'JAN', 'SAM']

def check_suite(name, suite):
    my_suite = Suites[suite] #I want my_suite to = ['NATE', 'TOM', 'TED', 'JAN', 'SAM']
    return name in suite #I want to return True or False
```

and in views.py I'm trying to find out that user_in_suite is True

```
 from .helper import check_suite
 from .helper import Suites

 def apps(request):
    user_name = 'NATE'
    suite_to_check = 'NAME_SUITE'
    user_in_suite = check_suite(name=user_name, suite=suite_to_check)
```

But I'm getting an error for helper.py: **'classobj' object has no attribute '__getitem__**

Comment: Maybe you should instantiate that class?

Comment: The short answer is `name in getattr(Suites(), suite)` but that looks like  code nightmare to me... what are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I'm just trying to  find a way in views.py, to see if a user (which will actually be more like: user_name = str(request.user.name)) is part of a given list (NAME_SUITE = ['NATE', 'TOM',..for example)

Comment: So why not just do that? why does `NAME_SUITE` need to be in a class of its own and why do you need to reference it via a string rather than just calling the variable?

Comment: I'm going to add more 'suites' to this eventually. I want an extendable way to see if person X is of list Y

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_suite(name, suite):
    my_suite = Suites.__dict__[suite] # __dict__ gives you access to the dictionary of class.
    return name in my_suite
```

This should solve your problem.